# Android SQLite create table with encrypted column names

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, encryption

I'm running into issues trying to run a CREATE TABLE statement for sqlite3 on Android. This is because I'm trying to encrypt the columns of the database. Does anyone know why it won't accept the encrypted values as column names?

Here is the error that I receive:

```
10-27 17:46:34.591: E/Database(697): Failure 1 (unrecognized token: 
338268F19CB9A68A39035AB5D733F931") on 0x232d40 when preparing 
'CREATE TABLE db_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
BB2BFFB83A95C39D864C9A52D5A5E2CC TEXT,338268F19CB9A68A39035AB5D733F931 
EXT,916D636E4793AB190F05F4F1EF6273A8 TEXT, 
UNIQUE(BB2BFFB83A95C39D864C9A52D5A5E2CC) ON CONFLICT ABORT);'.
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unquoted column names are not allowed to start with a digit

Comment: this is simply not true.  I would downvote but not enough rep yet.  see my answer below.

Comment: @EvanR. Yes, I should have been more specific

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String CROSSFIT_400MRUN = "'400m_Run'";
```

surround your # with single quotes, and it'll work:

[image]

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html